# Is any event other than PopViewController raised on UINavigationController on page pop?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my app, if I tap the Back button on the navigation bar rapidly, then `PopViewController` doesn't seem to be called sequentially for every page. Is there any event in `UINavigationController` that is raised on page pop regardless of how fast the Back button is tapped? Also, why does iOS seem to be not raising `PopViewController` in order?

Comment: You question is no clear.

Comment: What do you mean by `PopViewController` doesn't seem to be called? What are you doing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly your issue, but I came across something similar recently and found that if I tapped quickly enough on the back button then `popToViewController:` was called instead.